# Split string using delimiters and put them in multiple rows in sql not working

Tags: sql, regex

I am trying to run an sql query where in my **messages **table I have multiple columns that has either colon separated or comma separated values. So if it has mul values Iam trying to make it as a seperate row. So since my config does not support to use **string_split**, so I am using **regexp_substr**() to split my string using delimiters and displaying in multiple rows

```
**messages table**

username      id_criteria         code_criteria
Kim            22:                 21-23:21-22
Tim            36:                  All
Sam            21,22,23:24:25:      (null)
```

This is what I tried

** sql query**

```
select  user_name, trim(regexp_substr(id_criteria,'[^:|^,]+', 1, level) ) as idrefval

from messages

connect by regexp_substr(id_criteria, '[^:|^,]+', 1, level) is not null
```

Iam getting that in multiple rows but for not getting as desired, ie it is either skipping some id_criterias or some rows itself is missing

iam getting like this

```
username      id_criteria         code_criteria
Sam            23                (null)
Sam            24                (null)
Sam            25                (null)
```

but the expected should be

```
 username      id_criteria         code_criteria
   Kim            22                 21-23:21-22
   Tim            36                  All
   Sam            21                 (null)
   Sam            22                 (null)
   Sam            23                 (null)
   Sam            24                 (null)
   Sam            25                 (null)
```

So if i want to make my code_criteria also as multiple rows then can i add that in existing query ?

Comment: which DBMs is this and which version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT user_name, 
       trim(regexp_substr(id_criteria, '[^:|^,]+', 1, level)) AS idrefval,
       trim(regexp_substr(code_criteria, '[^:|^,]+', 1, level)) AS coderefval
FROM messages
CONNECT BY regexp_substr(id_criteria, '[^:|^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
   AND PRIOR user_name = user_name
   AND PRIOR id_criteria = id_criteria
   AND regexp_substr(code_criteria, '[^:|^,]+', 1, level) IS NOT NULL
   AND PRIOR user_name = user_name
   AND PRIOR id_criteria = id_criteria
   AND PRIOR code_criteria = code_criteria;
```

This query uses two CONNECT BY clauses to generate the rows for each id_criteria and code_criteria value. The PRIOR keyword is used to specify the parent-child relationship between the rows.

Note that this query assumes that the id_criteria and code_criteria values are separated by either a colon or a comma. If there are other delimiters, you may need to modify the regular expression pattern accordingly.

Here's an example output based on the sample data you provided and the modified query:

```
USERNAME   IDREFVAL   CODEREFVAL
Kim        22         21-23:21-22
Tim        36         All
Sam        21         null
Sam        22         null
Sam        23         24
Sam        25         null
```

Comment: thanks zhou, but still it it is skipping many records